Reconfigure custom content configuration
If you run the following UIKit app, you will see a collection view with compositional layout (list layout) and a diffable data source.
When you tap on the right bar button item, the payment method changes, at which point I would like the collection view to show the appropriate payment button.
import UIKit
import PassKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, String>!
    
    var paymentMethod: String = " Pay" {
        didSet {
            var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
            // re-apply all the cell registrations (which is just one in this case) to show the changed payment method
            snapshot.reconfigureItems(snapshot.itemIdentifiers)
            dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        configureHierarchy()
        configureDataSource()
    }
    
    func configureHierarchy() {
        collectionView = .init(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = .init(title: "Toggle payment method", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(togglePaymentMethod))
    }
    
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { section, layoutEnvironment in
            let config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
            return NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: config, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func togglePaymentMethod() {
        paymentMethod = paymentMethod == "Cash" ? " Pay" : "Cash"
    }
    
    func configureDataSource() {
        let payCashAtDeliveryCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<PayCashAtDeliveryCell, String> { [weak self] cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            guard let self else { return }
            
            cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkout), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        let applePayButtonCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<PKPaymentButtonCell, String> { [weak self] cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            guard let self else { return }
            
            cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkout), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        
        dataSource = .init(collectionView: collectionView) { [weak self] collectionView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            guard let self else { return nil }
            
            return switch paymentMethod {
            case " Pay":
                collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: applePayButtonCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: itemIdentifier)
            default:
                collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: payCashAtDeliveryCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: itemIdentifier)
            }
        }
        
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, String>()
        snapshot.appendSections(["main"])
        snapshot.appendItems(["demo"])
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
    
    @objc func checkout() {
        print(">> \(#function)")
    }
}

class PayCashAtDeliveryCell: UICollectionViewListCell {
    let button: UIButton = {
        var buttonConfiguration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        
        var attributeContainer = AttributeContainer()
        attributeContainer.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        attributeContainer.foregroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        buttonConfiguration.attributedTitle = .init("Ordina", attributes: attributeContainer)
        
        return UIButton(configuration: buttonConfiguration, primaryAction: nil)
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.addSubview(button)
        button.pinToSuperview()
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class PKPaymentButtonCell: UICollectionViewListCell {
    let button = PKPaymentButton(paymentButtonType: .checkout, paymentButtonStyle: .automatic)
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.addSubview(button)
        button.pinToSuperview()
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func pin(
        to object: CanBePinnedTo,
        top: CGFloat = 0,
        bottom: CGFloat = 0,
        leading: CGFloat = 0,
        trailing: CGFloat = 0
    ) {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: object.topAnchor, constant: top),
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: object.bottomAnchor, constant: bottom),
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: object.leadingAnchor, constant: leading),
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: object.trailingAnchor, constant: trailing),
        ])
    }
    
    func pinToSuperview(
        top: CGFloat = 0,
        bottom: CGFloat = 0,
        leading: CGFloat = 0,
        trailing: CGFloat = 0,
        file: StaticString = #file,
        line: UInt = #line
    ) {
        guard let superview = self.superview else {
            print(">> \(#function) failed in file: \(String.localFilePath(from: file)), at line: \(line): could not find \(Self.self).superView.")
            return
        }
        
        self.pin(to: superview, top: top, bottom: bottom, leading: leading, trailing: trailing)
    }
    
    func pinToSuperview(constant c: CGFloat = 0, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
        self.pinToSuperview(top: c, bottom: -c, leading: c, trailing: -c, file: file, line: line)
    }
}

@MainActor
protocol CanBePinnedTo {
    var topAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor { get }
    var bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor { get }
    var leadingAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor { get }
    var trailingAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor { get }
}

extension UIView: CanBePinnedTo { }
extension UILayoutGuide: CanBePinnedTo { }

extension String {
    static func localFilePath(from fullFilePath: StaticString = #file) -> Self {
        URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(fullFilePath)").lastPathComponent
    }
}

As of right now, though, when you tap the right bar button item, the app crashes with error Thread 1: "Attempted to dequeue a cell for a different registration or reuse identifier than the existing cell when reconfiguring an item, which is not allowed. You must dequeue a cell using the same registration or reuse identifier that was used to dequeue the cell originally to obtain the existing cell. Dequeued reuse identifier: 1FBF2362-FBFA-4B63-9E6C-F685BE6ECD5E; Original reuse identifier: 40FCBBD5-0D1B-4845-9D22-1C6288B5FE79; Existing cell: <ReconfigureCustomContentConfiguration.PKPaymentButtonCell: 0x105010430; baseClass = UICollectionViewListCell; frame = (20 35; 353 44); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000262660>>".
The crash could be avoided by capturing paymentMethod instead of self in the cell provider of the data source:
dataSource = .init(collectionView: collectionView) { [paymentMethod] collectionView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
    switch paymentMethod {
    case " Pay":
        collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: applePayButtonCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: itemIdentifier)
    default:
        collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: payCashAtDeliveryCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: itemIdentifier)
    }
}

at which point you could add print statements to the cell registrations to see that they indeed get called when you change the payment method, still the collection view does not reflect the change and in any case it's more of a workaround that a proper solution.
I could have tried to make do with just one cell registration with a cell of type UICollectionViewListCell (i.e. without subclassing), but that gave me problems in other scenarios (Lags in UICollectionView accessories when animatedly applying a snapshot unless .disclosureIndicator() is also an accessory).
I could have also tried to make just one UICollectionViewListCell subclass and reconfigure it, or dequeue the cells with my own identifier, but then I remembered that if you use UIContentConfiguration instead of cell subclasses you get many benefits (mainly that you can reuse the configuration for table view cells as well, and that the cells self-size better (UICollectionViewListCell not resizing)).
So indeed I tried to make a custom content configuration for the pay with cash at delivery button and one for the apple pay button:
// ...

func configureDataSource() {
    let checkoutButtonCell = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> { [weak self] cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        guard let self else { return }
        
        switch paymentMethod {
        case " Pay":
            var contentConfiguration = ApplePayButtonListContentConfiguration()
            contentConfiguration.target = (self, #selector(checkout), .touchUpInside)
            cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
        default:
            var contentConfiguration = PayCashAtDeliveryButtonListContentConfiguration()
            contentConfiguration.target = (self, #selector(checkout), .touchUpInside)
            cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
        }
    }
    
    dataSource = .init(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: checkoutButtonCell, for: indexPath, item: itemIdentifier)
    }
    
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, String>()
    snapshot.appendSections(["main"])
    snapshot.appendItems(["demo"])
    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
}

// ...

struct PayCashAtDeliveryButtonListContentConfiguration: UIContentConfiguration {
    var target: (Any?, Selector, UIControl.Event)?
    
    func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
        PayCashAtDeliveryButtonListContentView(configuration: self)
    }
    
    func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> Self {
        self
    }
}
class PayCashAtDeliveryButtonListContentView: UIView, UIContentView {
    var configuration: UIContentConfiguration
    
    init(configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
        self.configuration = configuration
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configureSubviews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configureSubviews() {
        guard configuration is PayCashAtDeliveryButtonListContentConfiguration else {
            print(">> Wrong config. File: \(String.localFilePath()), line: \(#line)")
            return
        }
        
        let button: UIButton = {
            var buttonConfiguration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
            
            var attributeContainer = AttributeContainer()
            attributeContainer.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
            attributeContainer.foregroundColor = .systemBlue
            
            buttonConfiguration.attributedTitle = .init("Ordina", attributes: attributeContainer)
            
            return UIButton(configuration: buttonConfiguration, primaryAction: nil)
        }()
        addSubview(button)
        button.pinToSuperview()
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    }
}

struct ApplePayButtonListContentConfiguration: UIContentConfiguration {
    var target: (Any?, Selector, UIControl.Event)?
    
    func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
        ApplePayButtonListContentView(configuration: self)
    }
    
    func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> Self {
        self
    }
}
class ApplePayButtonListContentView: UIView, UIContentView {
    var configuration: UIContentConfiguration
    
    init(configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
        self.configuration = configuration
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configureSubviews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configureSubviews() {
        guard configuration is ApplePayButtonListContentConfiguration else {
            print(">> Wrong config. File: \(String.localFilePath()), line: \(#line)")
            return
        }
        
        let button = PKPaymentButton(paymentButtonType: .checkout, paymentButtonStyle: .automatic)
        addSubview(button)
        button.pinToSuperview()
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    }
}

which works, but also gets me the warning Warning: You are setting a new content configuration to a cell that has an existing content configuration, but the existing content view does not support the new configuration. This means the existing content view must be replaced with a new content view created from the new configuration, instead of updating the existing content view directly, which is expensive. Use separate registrations or reuse identifiers for different types of cells to avoid this. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIContentConfigurationAlertForReplacedContentView to catch this in the debugger..
Which made me think that I had to make do with just one content configuration, which I've tried:
// ...

func configureDataSource() {
    let checkoutButtonCell = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> { [weak self] cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        guard let self else { return }
        
        var contentConfiguration = CheckoutButtonListContentConfiguration(
            paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
            buttonTarget: self,
            buttonAction: #selector(checkout)
        )
        cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
    }
    
    dataSource = .init(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: checkoutButtonCell, for: indexPath, item: itemIdentifier)
    }
    
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, String>()
    snapshot.appendSections(["main"])
    snapshot.appendItems(["demo"])
    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
}

// ...

struct CheckoutButtonListContentConfiguration: UIContentConfiguration {
    let paymentMethod: String
    let buttonTarget: Any
    let buttonAction: Selector
    
    init(paymentMethod: String, buttonTarget: Any, buttonAction: Selector) {
        self.paymentMethod = paymentMethod
        self.buttonTarget = buttonTarget
        self.buttonAction = buttonAction
    }
    
    func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
        CheckoutButtonListContentView(configuration: self)
    }
    
    func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> Self {
        self
    }
}
class CheckoutButtonListContentView: UIView, UIContentView {
    var configuration: UIContentConfiguration
    var button: UIButton!
    
    init(configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
        self.configuration = configuration
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configureSubviews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configureSubviews() {
        guard let config = configuration as? CheckoutButtonListContentConfiguration else {
            print(">> Wrong config. File: \(String.localFilePath()), line: \(#line)")
            return
        }
        
        let button: UIButton = switch config.paymentMethod {
        case " Pay":
            PKPaymentButton(paymentButtonType: .checkout, paymentButtonStyle: .automatic)
        default:
            PayCashAtDeliveryButton()
        }
        button.addTarget(config.buttonTarget, action: config.buttonAction, for: .touchUpInside)
        addSubview(button)
        button.pinToSuperview()
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    }
}

class PayCashAtDeliveryButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        
        var attributeContainer = AttributeContainer()
        attributeContainer.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        attributeContainer.foregroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        configuration.attributedTitle = .init("Ordina", attributes: attributeContainer)
        
        self.configuration = configuration
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

but the collection view does not show the updated payment method, even though the cell registration gets called every time it changes (which you can verify by adding a print statement to it).
--
By the way I' capturing weak self in the closures instead of unowned self because it seems safer to me, since UIKit does not always work as expected for me and also since Apple in the guided project "Modern Collection Views" more often than not does so as well.
Also note that unlike in the question UICollectionView List With Custom Configuration - how to pass changes in cell to view controller?, I expose some alternative approaches and their problems.
If my post existed when I first got the mentioned crash error, I would have saved time.

Change
var configuration: UIContentConfiguration 

to
var configuration: UIContentConfiguration {
    didSet {
        configureSubviews()
    }
}

and remove the subviews in the content view initialization:
subviews.forEach {
    $0.removeFromSuperview()
}

Edit: Please note that I don't know who else gave this answer to similar questions before I did.
